# Apache VirtualHost running but page cannot be displayed

Tags: vhosts

I was configuring on my local machine and every thing seems correct but it's not working or working weirdly.

I have tried all suggestions and no success.

**My problem is**

- I cant access my V host with the ServerName i defined.

> My current v host configuration is

---

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:80>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DocumentRoot "c:/web/Apache24/htdocs/myproj"
    ServerName www.myproj.dev 

        <Directory C:/web/Apache24/htdocs/myproj>
          Require all granted
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>




<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot c:/web/Apache24/htdocs
  ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

My hosts file includes `127.0.0.2 www.myproj.dev`

---

> running in **httpd -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS** cmd gives me

VirtualHost configuration:

- 127.0.0.2:80    www.myproj.dev (C:/web/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:31)
- *:80            localhost (C:/web/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:45)
- [This is my localhost screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoYCC.png)
- [And V host screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yJrt.png)

if i change 127.0.0.2 to 127.0.0.1 in httpd-vhost.conf and host file then entered 127.0.0.1 in the url i can access my vhost folder and should also localhost to access htdocs folder.

Comment: did you add a host entry for 127.0.0.2 pointing to www.myproj.dev? I would suggest keep it 127.0.0.1 with a host entry to the same

Comment: Yes i did, but still no luck also Exhausted all options provided by others and now i am forced to ask my own question

Comment: Is it issue related to name resolution or DNS cause i could see the V Host with DUMP_VHOSTS